# Multiple errors while creating new Angular application

Tags: node.js, angular

Starting to lean angular, but I am running into issues during the CLI process creating a new app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried Clearing Cache, rebooted, deleted and re created.

```
> node --version
v12.4.0
```

```
> ng --version
@angular-devkit/architect    0.800.3
@angular-devkit/core         8.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.0.3
@schematics/angular          8.0.3
@schematics/update           0.800.3
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

```
> ng new my-first-app
npm WARN deprecated mixin-deep@1.3.1: Critical bug fixed in v2.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@2.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm ERR! path A:\Test\Test\my-first-app\node_modules\.babel-runtime.DELETE
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'A:\Test\Test\my-first-app\node_modules\.babel-runtime.DELETE' -> 'A:\Test\Test\my-first-app\node_modules\babel-runtime'
```

Comment: Node 10.16.0 is technically the latest stable version. So maybe try that instead of 12.4.

Comment: @caden311 10.16 is LTS (long term support) but 12 is the "current" stable release.

Comment: Mm seems to be something of permissions. You can try (just to try) with sudo, to rule out that it's permissions

Comment: unfortunately using windows with no elevated permission options. I was hoping that wasn't the conclusion in the long run.

Comment: Reboot your computer. It's probably a file lock and rebooting will unlock it.

Comment: Tried it and it still hangs up at the .babel-runtime.Delete. It creates the folders, files, and node_modules in the directory up until the babel-runtime.

Comment: is this error just kicking up on the one particular .babel-runtime and installing all the other packages anyway?